# Big Graph Traversal

Tags: javascript, graph, traversal

Looking to see if someone could walk me through this question as it blew my mind when it came up and I could not get through it and its killing me.

the mocha specs are as follows

[image]

and the problem is:

[image]

Any help on this would be amazing as I struggled strongly with it and have no solutions

my start was`

```
function findNeighbors(node, matrix) {
    

 const row = node[0];
  const col = node[1];
  const neighbors = [];


    if (row > 0 && matrix[row - 1][col] < -5) neighbors.push([row - 1, col]);


    if (col < matrix[row].length - 1 && matrix[row][col + 1] < -5) neighbors.push([row, col + 1]);


    if (row < matrix.length - 1 && matrix[row + 1][col] < -5) neighbors.push([row + 1, col]);


    if (col > 0 &&  matrix[row][col - 1] < -5) neighbors.push([row, col - 1]);


    return neighbors;
  
}`
```

update: still missing some components if anyone could help but got a few done
[image]